# how to get nested tags with a loaded html page using python or php?

Tags: php, python, html, tags

How to do it?

How to get nested tags with a loaded html page using python or php?

Could you give me maybe a site where I can learn?

```
from HTMLParser import HTMLParser
import urllib

class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):

    def handlestarttag(self, tag, attrs):
        print "Poczatek %s" % tag

    def handleendtag(self, tag):
        print "Koniec %s tag" % tag

    def handledata(self, data):
        print "Dane %s" % data

p = MyHTMLParser()
input = urllib.urlopen('url')
html = input.read()
input.close()
p.feed(html)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/):

Here is an example for you:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Use urlopen to read web pages, this is only an e
test_input = r'<html><body><div id="bar"><p>Foo</p></div></body></html>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(test_input)

print soup.find('div', {'id': 'bar'}).p.text
```

This yields:

```
Foo
```

Look into the docs for BS for more examples. The important thing here is to use an existing library, and not try to create one for your own.